# surfaceCreated never called when activity theme = Theme.Dialog

Tags: surfaceview, android-dialog

I have a dialog activity, this is how I configure it in the Manifest file:

```
<activity
    android:name=".VideoDialogPreviewAct"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_video_dialog_preview"
    android:parentActivityName=".VideoResultsScreenAct"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.MES.MySperm.VideoResultsScreenAct" />
</activity>
```

Inside the activity I have only a SurfaceView :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    tools:context=".VideoDialogPreviewAct">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/MainSurface"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to play a video using this surface,
This Is my main Java code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_dialog_preview);
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

    mPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.MainSurface);
    mPreview.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListner);
    mPreview.setZOrderOnTop(true);  
    Create_Surface();
}

private void Create_Surface()
{

      holder = mPreview.getHolder();
      holder.addCallback(this);
      holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
      holder.setFixedSize(getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), 0);
      //holder.setFixedSize(100, 100);
      mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
     Play_Video();

}
```

My problem is that "surfaceCreated" method never called.

If I change the activity style to a Full screen mode then everything work fine.

Is someone is familiar with this problem?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem. For me it was because the View size was being set to 0, and therefore the surface was never created. I checked this by setting a specific size, and all of a sudden the callbacks were called. (Same, apparently, holds if the View is laid out off-screen).

So there may be something in your theme that is affecting the size or location of your View causing it to not be displayed.